# VBScript sendkeys, Trying to do CTRL+ALT+DOWN

Tags: vbscript

The code i am using is:

```
    set x = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    x.sendkeys("{CTRL}{ALT}{DOWN}")
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> as modifiers, use `^` and `%` respectively.  So, in your case you want `^%{DOWN}`.